# Guarantee that future properties of an `interface` will not have values of a particular type

Tags: typescript, types

I have an `interface` that is commonly logged (it's a distributed tracing context). My project also has a particular type to represent secrets, and I want to make sure that objects of type `Secret` are never added to this `interface`.

How can I restrict the type of any new properties added to the `interface`?

For example, here's what the current interface looks like:

```
interface TraceMetadata {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  time: Date;
}
```

I'd like to have a type-level guarantee that somebody won't do this:

```
interface TraceMetadata {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  time: Date;
  userSecret: Secret; // bad!
}
```

How can I do this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really any mechanism in TypeScript which will prevent this directly, as far as I know.  If the compiler allowed you to use self-referential interface declarations you could get this to happen, but it looks like TS4.0 and above doesn't allow for that (see [microsoft/TypeScript#40315](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40315) for more info).

Instead, you could come up with a sentinel type alias that will produce a compiler warning if and only if someone adds a `Secret`-valued property to the `TraceMetadata` interface.  For example:

```
type VerifyExtends<T, U extends T> = void;
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type TraceMetadataProperties = ValueOf<TraceMetadata>;
type AcceptableTraceMetadataProperties = Exclude<TraceMetadataProperties, Secret>;

/* NOTE WELL! */
// If there is an error in the next line of code, then someone has put a Secret
// value into TraceMetadata.  You should find out who and tell them to
// be ashamed of themselves.
type TraceMetadataHasNoSecrets = VerifyExtends<AcceptableTraceMetadataProperties,
  TraceMetadataProperties // <-- error here if someone has been naughty
>;
```

The `VerifyExtends<T, U>` type will only allow you to specify a `T` and `U` type where `U extends T`.  The type `TraceMetadataProperties` is the union of all property types in `TraceMetadata`, while `AcceptableTraceMetadataProperties` is that type with any `Secret` values removed.  If `TraceMetadataProperties extends AcceptableTraceMetadataProperties`, then everything is fine, as every property of `TraceMetadata` is acceptable.  Otherwise, there is a property of `TraceMetadata` which is *not* acceptable, and you'll get an error.

The fact that the error appears inside this sentinel type alias and not on the offending properties of `TraceMetadata` is sub-optimal.  But if you comment the sentinel type enough, hopefully someone will be able to understand what the warning means.

---

Let's test it out.

With this definition, there are no compiler warnings:

```
interface TraceMetadata {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  time: Date;
}

type TraceMetadataHasNoSecrets = VerifyExtends<AcceptableTraceMetadataProperties,
  TraceMetadataProperties // okay
>;
```

But with this definition, there is:

```
interface TraceMetadata {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  time: Date;
  userSecret: Secret; // bad!
}

type TraceMetadataHasNoSecrets = VerifyExtends<AcceptableTraceMetadataProperties,
  TraceMetadataProperties // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--
// Type 'ValueOf<TraceMetadata>' does not satisfy the constraint 
// 'string | number | Date'.
>;
```

Hopefully in the case where there actually is a compiler warning, someone will look at the sentinel type error, and see `error here if someone has been naughty` and `someone has put a Secret value into TraceMetadata` and be able to rectify the issue.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#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)

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to extend this check to cover the case where some of the properties might themselves be objects, in which case we'd need to verify that none of *their* properties are Secrets?

I've been playing around with a `ContainsSecret` type check, but it doesn't work the way that I'd expect:

``` type ContainsString<T> = T extends string ? T : (T extends {[k: string]: ContainsString<T>} ? T : never); const a: ContainsString<number> = 2; // this (unexpectedly) typechecks ```